# What is the meaning or purpose of "nach hin"?

Tags: meaning

These sentences are [found in DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=nach%20hin&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=10):

> er nahm, was in Menschenseelen als Phantasie auftrat, seiner Tatsächlichkeit **nach hin**

> Ein schmaler Balkon zog sich vor dem Zimmer seiner ganzen Länge **nach hin**.

What is the purpose/meaning of the "nach hin"s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Nach hin** is not a unit with a meaning of its own. **Hin** and **nach** are separate words, each with its own function and meaning.

- In the sentences you quoted, **hin** is the trailing part of a separable verb: **hinnehmen** in the first sentence, (sich) **hinziehen** in the second.
- **Nach** is a preposition governing the dative, with the peculiarity that it can be placed *after* the nominal group - **seiner Tatsächlichkeit** in the first sentence, **seiner ganzen Länge** in the second.

So the structure of your first sentence is:

**Er nahm** (Akkusativobjekt) (Adverbiale Bestimmung) **hin.**

where

- Akkusativobjekt = **was in Menschenseelen als Phantasie auftrat**
- Adverbiale Bestimmung = **seiner Tatsächlichkeit nach**

Im leaving the second sentence as an exercise.

Comment: Deutsche ist sehr kompliziert!